# OData Itemservice throws Null Reference

Tags: odata

I searched using the endpoint:

```
http://url/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items?sc_apikey=D5471CCA-DB0D-4260-A588-3D15025BA5CF&$expand=FieldValues&$filter=contains(FieldValues/Summary,'test')
```

But this returned an exception:

```
 "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
            "type": "System.NullReferenceException",
            "stacktrace": "   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, Boolean checkLocation)\r\n   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.GetContextIndexRanking(IIndexable indexable)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Min(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.IContextIndexRankable.GetContextIndexRanking(IIndexable indexable)\r\n   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.FetchIndex.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<RankContextIndexes>b__0(ISearchIndex i)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at
```

Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Does your Sorl instance is running and available?

Comment: also, make sure no error in the rebuild index.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is thrown in code:

```
public static IProviderSearchContext CreateSearchContext(IIndexable indexable)
{
  return GetIndex(indexable).CreateSearchContext(SearchSecurityOptions.EnableSecurityCheck);
}
```

Sitecore translates the `IIndexable` into a valid index for item. And then it creates a search context on that index.

The exception is thrown because the translation returns `null` *(some item from your query doesn’t map to any index)*.

Make sure that itemservice search index is configured as **“index all templates, except specific ones”**,  but NOT as **“exclude all templates, except specific ones”**.